# Exception thrown in a Constructor

Tags: c++

I'm trying to understand what problems can occur when a constructor throws an exception.

For example, part of this code:

```
#include <iostream>

class X
{
public:
    X(int);
    ~X();
private:
    int* m;
};

X::X(int y)
{
    m = new int(y);
    throw std::exception();
}

X::~X()
{
    delete m;
    std::cout << "Destructor" << std::endl;
}

//---------------------------------------
int main()
{
    try
    {
        X a(4);
    }
    catch (const std::exception&)
    {
        std::cout << "ex" << std::endl;
    }
    system("pause");
    // output 
    /*  ex
        Press any key to continue . . .
    */
}
```

The destructor doesn't get called, so it's a memory leak!

1) Is it possible solve this problem without using any smart pointers?

2) My main question is what problems can occur when a constructor throws an exception (for example, when we have a hierarchy of classes, or class members who may throw an exception)?

Comment: That's why we have [RAII](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii). In your case, if `m` was a `std::unique_ptr<int>`, there would be no leak.

Comment: *"is posiable solve this problem without using any smart pointers?"* - strange question given that this problem is caused by the lack of use of smart pointer

Comment: Without using smart pointers? Sure, you may catch the exception, delete `m`, and rethrow, as always.

Answer (score 0):

> my main question is what problems can be when constructor throw an exception

just as with throwing in general, there's nothing specific about a constructor.

C++ is designed to have throws in constructors.

Your example:

```
m = new int(y);
throw std::exception();
```

is bad anywhere.

Use:

```
auto m = std::make_unique<int>(y);
throw std::exception();
```

instead.

Comment: _Is bad anywhere_ - actually, it is not in OP's case in a member function, if destructor is then called. Note that `m` is a member variable, not automatic variable.

Comment: @DanielLangr Thanks, didn't catch that.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux well function try-blocks are not specific to constructors, they only happen to be the only way to immediately catch an exception from a member initializer.